# CLLocation Manager Delegate is not getting called in iPhone OS 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have to run my app in iPhone OS 4.0.  (in simulator).

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self newLocationUpdate];
}

-(void)newLocationUpdate
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

In this CLLocationManager delegate method is not getting called. what changes should we make so that delegate method is called?

Answer (score 3):

I'm suspecting that your "locationManager" instance is getting released prematurely.

Is it a property? 
If so, then change from:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]] init];
```

to:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

and ensure the property is declared:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager * locationManager;
```

And don't forget to release it later, where appropriate.

Comment: I agree that a retained property would make things simpler to maintain in the long run, but if you just assign a location manager with a retain count of 1 (alloc, init and no autorelease) to a retained property it would end up with a retain count of 2 and you have a leak on your hand. So use the "self." approach with a retained property and add an autorelease to the end of that alloc-init.